awk gsub not replacing all instances of period in field
I am trying to parse some output so that eventually I can use declare to create multiple environment variables. The problem I am encountering is that the awk statement I have is not substituting all occurrences of period in the first field ($1).
The input is generated from:
etherNIC=$(nmcli --get-values NAME connection show)
nmcli connection show $etherNIC | grep -i  "ipv4.gateway\|ipv4.route" > ./ipv4settings.txt

... which looks like this:
cat ./ipv4settings.txt
ipv4.gateway:                           192.168.2.1
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)

This is is the output from awk:
cat ./ipv4settings.txt | awk '{ split($0, array, ":") ; gsub( "\\.", "_", $1 ) ;  gsub( ":" , "=" , $1 ) ; print $1$2 }'
ipv4_gateway=192.168.2.1
ipv4_routes=--
ipv4_route-metric=-1
ipv4_route-table=0

The problem is that gsub( "\\.", "_", $1 ) is not replacing all occurrences of . in $1. The output I want is:
ipv4_gateway=192.168.2.1
ipv4_routes=--
ipv4_route_metric=-1
ipv4_route_table=0

In this case the second . has been correctly replaced with _.
awk --version
GNU Awk 5.1.0, API: 3.0 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0-p9, GNU MP 6.2.0)
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2020 Free Software Foundation.
<snip>

Edit #1
I just realized that the correct output for ipv4.route-table should be 0 (unspec) not 0.
Edit #2
As mentioned by @markp-fuso the original property names ipv4.route-metric and ipv4.route-table have only one period (.). This is why you should code while tired. Also, I'm switching my accepted answer to @markp-fuso.

As an aside: You split into array but never use it. Instead, you rely on the default splitting at spaces, which is what populates $1, $2, etc.

the strings you're complaining about only contain a single period and that period is being replaced; from your expected results it appears that you also want to replace hyphens with an underscore (hint: a period is not the same as a hyphen); cyrus' answer demonstrates how to replace both periods and hyphens with underscores

Just a small remark; as you're using awk eventually then you could skip the grep step: awk '/^ipv4\.(gateway|route)/ {...}'

@markp-fuso Yes, I didn't realize that until I posted the question. I spent too much time trying to solve the problem.

if you're looking to create variable=value clauses then you also need to consider wrapping the value components in quotes (eg, ipv4_route_table='0 (unspec)')

Assumptions/understandings:

we're only interested in nmcli output that starts with the strings ipv4.gateway or ipv4.route
we want to replace variable:    value with variable='value'
all periods and hyphens in variable are to be replaced with underscores
the colon + white space is to be replaced with an equal sign
value is to be wrapped in single quotes; the quotes are required in case value includes white space (eg, ipv4_route_table='0 (unspec)')

Adding additional input line to cover a) no spaces after the :, b) chains of white space in the value, c) : in the value and d) trailing white space in the value (NOTE: don't know if b, c or d can occur so possible overkill):
$ cat ipv4settings.txt
ipv4.gateway:                           192.168.2.1
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)
ipv4.route-stuff:0   (unspec)   leave:these:colons:alone   

NOTE: there a few spaces on the end of the last line
One awk idea
$ cat ipv4.awk
BEGIN { sq = "\x27" }                                  # define single quote

/^ipv4[.](gateway|route)/ {                            # lines that start with ipv4.gateway or ipv4.route

        pos   = index($0,":")                          # find 1st ":"
        var   = substr($0,1,pos-1)                     # parse out variable name
        value = substr($0,pos+1)                       # parse out value

        gsub(/[.-]/,"_",var)                           # replace periods and hyphens
        gsub(/^[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$/,"",value)   # trim leading/trailing white space

        print var "=" sq value sq                      # print new line
}

NOTE:

while the /^ipvr[.](gateway|route)/ is overkill when running against OP's ip4vsettings.txt file ...
this same script can be fed the raw nmcli output to generate the same result

Running against OP's ipv4settings.txt file:
$ awk -f ipv4.awk ipv4settings.txt
ipv4_gateway='192.168.2.1'
ipv4_routes='--'
ipv4_route_metric='-1'
ipv4_route_table='0 (unspec)'
ipv4_route_stuff='0   (unspec)   leave:these:colons:alone'

Applying to the raw output from the nmcli call:
$ nmcli connection show "${etherNIC}" | awk -f ipv4.awk
ipv4_gateway='192.168.2.1'
ipv4_routes='--'
ipv4_route_metric='-1'
ipv4_route_table='0 (unspec)'
ipv4_route_stuff='0   (unspec)   leave:these:colons:alone'


gsub(/^[[:space:]]*|[[:space:]]*$/,"",value) : wouldn't using + be more efficient instead of *, esp since the rest of the logic isn't dependent on this gsub() returning a positive value.

Let file.txt content be
ipv4.gateway:                           192.168.2.1
ipv4.routes:                            --
ipv4.route-metric:                      -1
ipv4.route-table:                       0 (unspec)

Observe that your fields are separated with : following by plurality of white-space characters, rather than sole :. Therefore I propose following solution
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":[[:space:]]+";OFS="="}{gsub(/[.]/,"_",$1);$1=$1;print}' file.txt

gives output
ipv4_gateway=192.168.2.1
ipv4_routes=--
ipv4_route-metric=-1
ipv4_route-table=0 (unspec)

Explanation: I use FS (field separator) and OFS (output field separator) to inform GNU AWK how fields are sheared in input (FS) and how should be separated in output (OFS). I use gsub to replace literal dot ([.]) using underscore in 1st field, then I do $1=$1 in order to trigger string rebuilt in case there was not dot (i.e. when gsub did nothing) and print whole line.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.3.1)

I'm marking this as correct as it fixes a problem that hadn't seen in my output requirements. This correctly shows a value of 0 (unspec) for ipv4.route-table.
